# deformation of abelian varieties

Tags: abelian-varieties, deformation-theory

$k$ is a field of characteristic p, $C_k$ is the category of all artinian local rings with residue field **an extension** of $k$. $A$ is a dim-$g$ abelian variety over $k$, $L$ is a CM field with $[L:\mathbb Q]=2g$, $\alpha: O_L\rightarrow End(A)$ is an embedding of $O_L$ into $A$'s endomorphism ring. Consider the deformation functor $Def(A,\alpha)$ on the category of $C_k$. Can one recommend any reference for the representability of such deformation functors that allow a possible extension of the base field? Thank you very much!

Comment: Without change of base field, using Serre-Tate and Grothendieck-Messing, this amounts to lifting the Hodge filtration on $\mathbb{D}(A)$ in a way such that $O_L$ will respect it. In particular, we can do this over the univ. deformation of $A$, and it appears that we get a closed condition cutting out the required (formal) sub-scheme for us. I don't know what happens when you allow change of base field, but some Galois cohomology might show up. 

Comment: Without specifying polarization, there is just a formal abelian scheme over the deformation ring, so the deformation functor is only pro-representable. (This really happens: there exist formal abelian schemes over $p$-adic dvrs that have "complex mult." but tangential action on generic fiber of Lie alg. is *not* a CM type and hence are not algebraizable. Such examples are in a forthcoming book I am writing with Chai and Oort on CM-lifting problems.) Maybe you really want to know more generally about interaction of deformation rings with change in $k$? The story works in char-free way. (cont'd)

Comment: For complete local noetherian $\Lambda$, let $C_{\Lambda}$ be category of artin local $\Lambda$-algebras with same residue field $k$. (If $k$ perfect of char. $p > 0$ then $C_{W(k)}$ is same as $C_k$ in the question.) Let $\Lambda \rightarrow \Lambda'$ be local map between such rings, inducing $k \rightarrow k'$ on residue field. For a "structure" $X$ over $k$ whose formal def. functor $D_X$ on $C_{\Lambda}$ is pro-reptd by some $R$, is $D_{X_{k'}}$ on $C_{\Lambda'}$ pro-reptd by $\Lambda' \widehat{\otimes}_{\Lambda} R$? Yes, quite often. See Rim's expose in SGA7 for the technique. 

Comment: In particular, for any proper $k$-scheme $X$ and the flat deformation theory of $X$, this all works out in the affirmative. For abelian varieties the same method works, or much much simpler is to make a direct analysis of tangent space, in view of the concrete structure of the formal deformation ring! Then as Keerthi said, by using separatedness (and representability -- as algebraic spaces in the absence of projectivity) of Hom-functors for abelian schemes (building on Hilbert functors) one can incorporate "closed" conditions involving endomorphisms to get an affirmative answer. 

Comment: To Brian: Thanks for the explanation; however, in my question I am not requiring all the residue fields are the same extension of the base field! What about this case?

Comment: Dear Taisong: My 2nd comment is addressing your question. Think about the meaning of the statement I made about behavior of formal deformation ring with respect to local extension of the coefficient ring.  For example, if you make an extension of perfect residue fields $k'/k$, then to say that the deformation ring for residue field $k$ still "works" for objects with residue field $k'$ really is the same as saying that completed scalar extn by $W(k) \rightarrow W(k')$ carries a universal pro-object to a universal pro-object. Let me know if it's still unclear that I have addressed your question.

Comment: Dear Taisong: It's analogous to the behavior of moduli schemes with respect to extension of the base scheme (but you're right to be bothered that in certain respects it is more subtle, due to how the results are usually stated).  My recollection is that Rim's expose which I mention does treat these compatibility issues for deformation rings in a pretty systematic and general manner (albeit with perhaps too much formalism, so may be best to have in mind a "real" example when reading his stuff).

Comment: Dear Brian--Regarding your first point about there not being a CM lift to characteristic zero: is the issue that $O_L$ need not be stable under some Rosati involution? If we manage to find a formal lift with polarization respected by $O_L$, then do we win? 

Comment: Dear Keerthi: if you have a formal deformation of the polarization then $O_L$ is irrelevant.  As you know, a proper formal scheme with a rel. ample line bundle is algebraizable.  So the problem is that there's no polarization, regardless of behavior with respect to $O_L$-action. But you may like the following fact: the CM-type condition for the $L$-action on the geometric generic fiber of the Lie algebra is not just necessary for algebraicity, but also sufficient!  The proof uses Serre-Tate and Grothendieck-Messing all over the place (and handles $p = 2$ without breaking a sweat).